# Can there be a special flag for overly duplicated questions?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

I pretty regularly browse the new questions on Stack Overflow and notice that an unbelievable number of questions are about `NullPointerException`s or floating point arithmetic. While for `NullPointerException` questions there is a bubble that pops up, there is not one for floating point arithmetic. I have a two part proposal for this

1. There should be a bubble for floating point arithmetic
2. People who ignore these bubbles (and other bubbles) should have a special punishment system for `x` number of questions that are obvious duplicates despite the bubble.

Is there a way this can be implemented?

Comment: You are also asking for a special flag, aren't you?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your points:

1. There already *is* a suggested questions popup when you create a new question.  It could possibly be made much more accurate so that the results you expect to see do, but if users ignore it already on *other* questions, I'm not sure what else could garner their attention.
2. I'm not a fan of necessarily punishing a user for not paying attention to the system-driven warning for duplicates, since it leaves a lot of unknown question space here.

   For example:

   - What is *x*?  When do we say that after *x* duplicates, that this one is ***definitely*** the canonical and best question-answer collection?  This can be a moving target, especially in a fast-developing technology where the canonical answer *can* change.
   - What is the punishment?  Do we prevent them from asking questions?  We already have limitations to that tune, so I don't see value in adding more on top of what already works rather nicely.
   - Users that ask a duplicate question may get a *better* answer than any preexisting questions could've offered here.  By implementing this, we'd potentially cut off valuable knowledge which could be amalgamated later.

Comment: That's true. I just feel like there are so many "look at my code, why do I have a `NullPointerException` questions". While there are sometimes good questions about `NullPointerException`s, a lot of them are practically debug requests.

Comment: @EliSadoff:  There *are* legitimate debug requests on NPEs out there which don't fall into the typical pattern; there's no reason to paint all of these questions with the same brush.  That said, it's not something that can automatically be deciphered through a process like a script or anything like that.